# elementary OS freezes randomly

Tags: programming, shell

I just installed elementary OS on my notebook and it's started randomly freeze. There was 50% of RAM available when it freezed. Any ideas?

**HP ProBook 650 G1**

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Nvidia card
see which version you are using. 
Install additional drivers

```
sudo apt install additional-drivers
```

the package name might be different but you can also find it in the app store

after it was installed check there which drivers you are using for your graphics card. 
I had such problems with nouveau drivers (open source drivers for Nvidia)

so I installed the latest drivers from Nvidia and everything was resolved

Comment: No, it has AMD. But I can try it.

Comment: perhaps there's drivers for AMD as well, don't have any experience with them

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to the Intel processor. I had a similar experience with a laptop with an Intel processor. What I did was open the terminal and run:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Change `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_idle.max_cstate=1"`

Save it (`Ctrl+O`), exit (`Ctrl+X`)

Then run

```
sudo update-grub
sudo reboot
```

Hope this helps. And make sure that the OS is updated as well.